# Slot Game in Py

Tags: python, debugging, youtube, program-entry-point

I am building a very basic slot machine in python. This is the first python code I am doing, and am following a ytb tutorial. Somehow I am not getting the right result in terminal when I am testing out the code.

```
MAX_LINES = 3

def deposit():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

                    return amount



def get_number_of_lines():
      while True:
        lines = input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ")? ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number of lines.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

                    return lines


def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = get_number_of_lines()
    print(balance, lines)

main()
```

This is the code I wrote so far.

And here is what I get in Terminal ( I am doing this in VsCode).

```
What would you like to deposit? $200

Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-3)? 3

None None. \<\<this should say 3 ...
```

and further I did not get yet, but its a struggle to find the answer to this problem, there were some other people under the YouTube video who struggle/d with the same output in terminal.

[image: photo of my screen when I run debug]

Comment: It looks like both of your `return ...` lines are indented too much. They should be indented by the same amount as the `while True:` above them.

Comment: @quamrana I tried changing it but it didn't do anything, it just gave me the "syntax error" message... :(

Comment: My comment still stands. But also see my answer . . .

Comment: @quamrana I think it works now! sorry I didn't see your full comment before where exactly it should be indented.

Comment: See the three answers below for the corrections to  the indentation. And once you fix that you may find that your code runs. I would also caution against YouTube videos, many of which are not of good quality. If you want to learn Python properly then use [The Official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: @OldBoy is right. I just wanted to show it's not just his opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to only `return` after the while loop has finished.
Also please try to maintain 4 spaces or one tab as the default indentation level.

```
MAX_LINES = 3

def deposit():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return amount



def get_number_of_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ")? ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number of lines.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return lines


def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = get_number_of_lines()
    print(balance, lines)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statements of both your functions are indented too far. So when the code reaches the `break` statement, the function returns but does not pass any value back to the caller, so the captured variable is set to `None`. They should both be at the same level of indentation as the controlling `while`, so they actually return a value when the `break` clause is initiated.

```
def deposit():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return amount



def get_number_of_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ")? ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number of lines.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return lines
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your `return ...` lines correctly:

```
MAX_LINES = 3

def deposit():
    while True:
        amount = input("What would you like to deposit? $")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount > 0:
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return amount

def get_number_of_lines():
    while True:
        lines = input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES) + ")? ")
        if lines.isdigit():
            lines = int(lines)
            if 1 <= lines <= MAX_LINES:
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number of lines.")
        else:
                    print("Please enter a number.")

    return lines

def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = get_number_of_lines()
    print(balance, lines)

main()
```

Sorry, yes the `while True:` in `def get_number_of_lines():` was also indented incorrectly.

Comment: The indentation of the original code isn't standardized. Please double check all indentations